# Wpf Ellipse cut top and bottom off

Tags: wpf, xaml, ellipse

I need to draw an Ellipse (or anything else?) that looks like my example (roughly drawed in paint what i mean)

[image: Ellipse]

Any Suggestions how to develop this ?

I tried Clip, but i can only cut off top or bottom then ( or am i doing sth wrong ?)

```
<Canvas Width="16" Height="16">
    <Ellipse Fill="Red" MinHeight="16"  Name="ellipse1" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" MinWidth="16" >
        <Ellipse.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,16,10"/>
        </Ellipse.Clip>
    </Ellipse>
</Canvas>
```

The best would be if it's a circle an dynamiclly changes the Size to the content

Thanks Markus

Comment: Can you draw a rectangle and clip it where it intersects with the ellipse?

Comment: A Rectangle with RadiusX and RadiusY set would pretty much do what you want, unless you *want* sharp edges. The path answer below can be exactly duplicated with a much-simpler rectangle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx)

```
<Canvas>
    <Path Data="M 30, 0 A 10,10 90 0 1 30,20 H 10 A 10,10 90 0 1 10,0 Z" 
          Fill="Red" Stroke="Black"/>
</Canvas>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm loving that screen shot that you've provided! Clip should be able to provide the top and bottom clipping that I think you're after, see below.

[image]

```
<Canvas Width="16" Height="16" Margin="80,50,421,254">
   <Ellipse Fill="Red" MinHeight="16"  Name="ellipse1" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" MinWidth="16" Height="100" Width="100" >
       <Ellipse.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,25,100,50"/>
       </Ellipse.Clip>
   </Ellipse>
</Canvas>
```

The properties of the RectangleGeometry are (in order) Left offset, Top offset, width, height. so start the clip region where you want the top cut off and stop it where you want the bottom cut off.